# Why does the BIML ScriptTask fail until I open the script in VS and save the package

Tags: ssis, script-task, biml

I have this BIML Script, which creates a Master and child package.  The child package has a ScriptTask in it that maps the value of a parent package variable to a child package variable.  When I Generate the packages in SSIS (Visual Studio 2015, target Sql Server 2014) they generate fine.  If I run the master package, the child fails with this error:

```
DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code:
Project name:  ST_GetJobLogIdHere
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

When I open the ScriptTask in the child, then close it again, the package is dirty so I save it.  After that, running the packages works properly.

Here's the BIML Script:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">

    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_GetJobLogId" Name="ST_GetJobLogIdScript" VstaMajorVersion="0">
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="vMasterJobLogId" DataType="Int32" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <ReadWriteVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="vJobLogId" DataType="Int32" />
            </ReadWriteVariables>
            <AssemblyReferences>
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
            <Files>
                <File Path="AssemblyInfo.cs" BuildAction="Compile">
                    using System.Reflection;

                    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ST_GetJobLogId")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ST_GetJobLogId")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @ BMI 2017")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
                    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                </File>
                <File Path="ScriptMain.cs" BuildAction="Compile">
                    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

                    namespace ST_GetJobLogId
                    {
                        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPoint]
                        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
                        {
                            public void Main()
                            {
                                int jobLogId = (int)Dts.Variables["User::vMasterJobLogId"].Value;
                                if (jobLogId != 0)
                                    Dts.Variables["User::vJobLogId"].Value = jobLogId;
                                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                            }
                            enum ScriptResults
                            {
                                Success = DTSExecResult.Success,
                                Failure = DTSExecResult.Failure
                            };
                        }
                    }
                </File>
            </Files>
        </ScriptTaskProject>
    </ScriptProjects>

    <Packages>
        <Package Name="Master" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="vMasterJobLogId" DataType="Int32">1</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecutePackage Name="PKG - Execute FixMe">
                    <ExternalProjectPackage Package="FixMe.dtsx" />
                </ExecutePackage>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
        <Package Name="FixMe" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="vJobLogId" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Script Name="SCR - Get vJobLogId from parent vMasterJobLogId" ProjectCoreName="ST_GetJobLogIdHere" >
                    <ScriptTaskProjectReference ScriptTaskProjectName="ST_GetJobLogIdScript" />
                </Script>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>

</Biml>
```

What am I missing?  Why is the package failing until I open the code window manually?
Thanks in advance for your help,
Simon

Comment: Checking it out now, but the quick thought is that if it magically starts working once you open/close the script task, then something is awry with the compiled bits in the package.

Comment: Hmmm, this works for me but I'm also on an experimental build of BimlExpress. Let me see if I can get a working repro with the public version of BimlExpress later this evening

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the help.

Comment: So you made me think to try it in a new project.  I left the VS Project at the default of SQL Server 2016 and this script worked and the packages worked.  Then I created another new project, changed the target to SQL Server 2014, ran the BIML, executed the master package and got the error.  Is there a flag I'm missing somewhere to have the BIML Express / BIML code generate a SQL Server 2014 code module?  Thanks.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't notice that nuance of the problem. I bet the biml compiler isn't factoring in the target version of the project. If that's the case, while inconvenient, [SSDT-BI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) is free to download so if you install that version and the corresponding BimlExpress/BidsHelper, I bet the scripts will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the comments above for clarification of the question.

It turns out that BIML Express/BidsHelper in Visual Studio 2015 does not know which target version of SQL Server is set in the Project properties.

The solution was to install VS2013 / SSDT 2014, and BIML Express for VS2013 to be able to generate the SSIS 2014 packages properly.

VS 2015 / SSDT / BIML Express will only generate Script Tasks for SQL Server SSIS 2016 packages.

Thanks to Bill for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when you're using VS2017 with SSDT and install the latest (preview) version of BimlExpress 2018.

Had the same problem with VS2015 and upgrading to the new version of BimlExpress fixed it.